# iOS Multicolumn table that changes number of columns per row on device flip

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I would like to create a table with multiple columns, each containing a button. It should basically look similar to the iPhone's or iPad's home screen. This I know can do by placing a certain number of buttons in each table cell.
My problem is however that I want to change the number of buttons in every row when the device is flipped. In landscape mode I can fit more buttons in one row.

For example: if in portrait mode the table looks like this:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

I would like it to look like this in landscape mode:
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy or difficult based on your experience really. This is what you essentially need to do:

1. Initially make sure the table delegate methods can render the cells appropriately based on the orientation ( landscape or portrait)
2. Listen to the orientation event and when that happens just do a reloadData on the table.  Try to read this [guide](http://www.bytesizecreations.com/2009/05/working-with-orientation-changes-on/) to get a better understanding about the changes to orientation and what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the number of buttons in a row a variable ex. `buttonsPerRow`, and when your view rotates change the value of that variable and reload your tableview.

To keep the viewcontroller tidy it helps to have a custom tableview cell that takes the number of buttons as a parameter, and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just pass `buttonsPerRow` to the cell.

Comment: Thank you, you answer is very similar to the other one. I wanted to select both as accepted answers, but StackOverflow doesn't allow that.